# How Can I Make A Dynamic Navbar

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to make my navbar dynamic so that when I am on that selected page the class **`active`** is added.
I know I can do as bellow, however, is there a simpler way even with Javascript so that I don't need to copy and paste a bunch of times?
(maybe with a different class?)

```
$a='home';

<nav>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link <?php if($a==Home) echo 'active';?>">home</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: i want to know your url.
like this ? example.com/home ?

Comment: Do you want to use just php? I've done something similar to this using Vue.js. Is that fine?

Comment: php is fine, the site is a local host using xampp

Comment: i tried this but when the if statement is present it dose not work`<html>`
`<head>`
`<style>`
`.mystyle {`
` color: red;`
`}`
`</style>`
`</head>`
`<body>`
`<a  href="url.php" class="nav-item">nav</a>`
`<a  href="#" class="nav-item">nav</a>`
`<script>`
`var navClass = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");`
`var path = window.location.href;`
`for (i = 0; i < navClass.length; i++) {`
`  if (navClass === path) {`
`    navClass[i].classList.add("mystyle");`
`  }`
`}`
`</script>`
`</body>`
`</html>`

Answer (score 0):

this is a JavaScript salutation:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .active {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <a  href="js" class="nav-item">Curent Page</a>
  <a  href="page2.html" class="nav-item">Difrent Page</a>
  <a  href="page3.html" class="nav-item">Difrent Page</a>
  <script>
  var navClass = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
  var path = window.location.href;

  for (i = 0; i < navClass.length; i++) {
   if (path.includes(navClass[i].href)) {
      navClass[i].classList.add("active");
    }
  }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

it takes the content of the `href` and sees if it is included in curent url if yes it adds a class